# Check if multiline textbox generated dynamically true code has overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that Rows property of textbox is allways 0 probably because code doesn't know how many rows textbox will have wenn is rendered. So i display 3 rows and overflow is hidden and i want add button that will open full text. But button is only shown if text box have more that 3 rows. So is there any way that i can check that in code.

```
TextBox text = new TextBox();
text.ID = "Poruka" + i;
text.Text = podaci.GetString(2);
text.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
text.Width = Unit.Pixel(535);
text.Height = Unit.Pixel(45);
text.Enabled = false;
text.Style.Add("overflow", "hidden");
PanelSadrzaj.Controls.Add(text);
if (text.Text.Length > 198 || ????)
{
    Button vise = new Button();
    vise.ID = "Vise" + i;
    vise.Text = "Prikaži cijelu poruku";
    vise.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
    vise.CssClass = "ButtonDodaj";
    vise.Font.Bold = true;
    vise.OnClientClick = "PrikaziPoruku_Click";
    PanelSadrzaj.Controls.Add(vise);
}
```

Edit:
Soultion is to add this funcuton, and call it in UpdatePanel in ContentTemplate.
Function code:

```
function CheckOverflow() {
        $("textarea").each(function () {
            var threshold = 2;
            var sender = $(this);
            var lineCount = sender.val().split("\n").length;
            var overflow = sender[0].offsetHeight < sender[0].scrollHeight - threshold;

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id.slice(-1);
            if (lineCount > 3 || overflow) {
                $('#Buttonid' + id).show();
            }
            else {
                $('#Buttonid' + id).hide();
            }
            alert(id);
        });
    }
```

UpdatePanel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(CheckOverflow);
        </script>
    <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks to [irongeek](/questions/tagged/irongeek)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example I'm assuming this is about multiline textbox in Web applications a.k.a `TextArea`. To achieve what you wanted, you need to write a bit of *javascript* and put it in your document ready.

Basically you need to:

1. monitor how many lines has been keyedin the the `TextArea`,
2. check for any content overflow,
3. show/ hide the *more button* accordingly.

There's no built-in function for getting the number of lines in `TextArea`, but you could emulate it by counting how many *line feed* characters (`\n`) instead. As for checking for content overflow you can do so by comparing the element's `offsetHeight` property with its `scrollHeight` property (assumed there's no horizontal overflow), for example:

```
$('#txtArea').on('input', function() {
  var threshold = 2; // number of pixel to account for border and etc
  var sender = $(this);        
  var lineCount = sender.val().split("\n").length;
  var overflow = sender[0].offsetHeight < sender[0].scrollHeight - threshold;

  if (lineCount > 3 || overflow) {
    $('#btnMore').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#btnMore').hide();
  }
}
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ps58d/

---

**Update**:

Change JSFiddle demo to match OP's example: http://jsfiddle.net/ps58d/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this as all the rows property does is set the number of rows visible to the user.

What I think you can do however is instead of using the `Width` property instead use the `Columns` property. That way you can have a set number of characters per row (e.g. 25, three rows would be 75 characters.)

e.g.

```
string[] mylines = TextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
int maxCharCount = TextBox1.Rows * TextBox1.Columns;

if (mylines.Count() > 3 || TextBox1.Text.Length > maxCharCount)
{
      //Show Button
}
```

Comment: Problem is if for example user type 50 characters and 2 newline that will be 4 line will this code recognize that.

Comment: You'll need to add logic to count the carriage and new line returns i.e. four lines of text will look like "Line1\r\nLine2\r\nVeryLong Line 3\r\nLast Line ". I also think you'll need to be careful to use a fixed width font otherwise you'll run into problems.

Comment: I've updated the sample code with what I was suggesting, haven't tested it in all scenarios though.

Comment: Nope its not working in all scenarios because newline characters are added by program wenn textbox is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `Multiline` `TextBox`, the whole text is in one line and it is split only for display purposes. in order to find the actual number of lines you have to use `MeasureString` as follows:

```
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
        int linesCount = (int)(size.Height / textBox1.Font.GetHeight());
    }
```

Comment: The name 'CreateGraphics' does not exist in the current context, Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo' to 'System.Drawing.Font'

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is a member of `Control`. You can use it in any form, or use `textBox1.CreateGraphics()`.